# Read and overwrite specific lines in a text file

Tags: java, filereader

I am writing a program in Java to update data on a text document. The update is triggered by a button (JButton).

In particular, I need to distinguish 3 lines in the document:

- the first one describes a float value called 'total'.
- the second describes a float value called 'fail'.
- the third describes a double value called 'rate'.

During program execution, I want the 3 lines of the document to be read and assigned to variables; once the button is pressed, the respective variables will have to overwrite the value in the document.

In order to achieve this I have reasoned as follows:

I declared the 3 private variables (total, fail and rate) initializing them to zero, and then did a read from the file where I assigned them the right value.

```
float total = 0.0f, fail = 0.0f;
double rate = 0d;

try {
  total = Float.parseFloat(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("failRate.txt")).get(0));
  fail = Float.parseFloat(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("failRate.txt")).get(1));
  rate = Double.parseDouble(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("failRate.txt")).get(2));
} catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

In the button, I have incremented the variables and an error already appears here:

> Variable 'total' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final

If I were to make the variables final, I couldn't change them, so that's not the right way.

I've tried making the variables public but in doing so, I notice that the variables are changed internally but not updated in the file.

So we come to the crucial point:

```
try {
  Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("failRate.txt")).set(1, Float.toString(fail));
  Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("failRate.txt")).set(2, Double.toString(rate));
} catch (Exception exception){exception.printStackTrace();}
```

Now that the variables are private, it also gives an error, but when they were public it still didn't work.

I also realise that going to read the whole file to overwrite only certain values is wrong, but I don't know any other way at the moment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I also realise that going to read the whole file to overwrite only certain values is wrong"* -- no, this is not wrong and is way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can see what your error/problems are based on your code and description. Consider creating a better code post, preferably a [mre]. Also to ease your creation of your MRE, and your debugging, best to do your GUI work and your file I/O work in separate, testable, classes.

Comment: And public vs private should have no bearing on your task, other than it is almost always best to make such variables private, and I recommend that you do so in this case.

Comment: But reading a file 3 times is wrong. Read it *once* and extract the values needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you made me realise that the function I was using was OK. In fact, it's not a reading problem (maybe the way I wrote it is not optimised, but for now I was just aiming to make it work), but a writing problem.
I need to find a function that allows me to write to the file at the line I choose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Variable 'total' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final

You need a "wrapper". I would change the type of `total` and `fail` to `double` and use an array.

```java
double[] values = new double[3];
button.addActionListener(e -> {
            Path path = Paths.get("failRate.txt");
            try {
                List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
                values[0] = Double.parseDouble(lines.get(0));
                values[1] = Double.parseDouble(lines.get(1));
                values[2] = Double.parseDouble(lines.get(2));
                BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path,
                                                            StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                            StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                                                            StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
                for (double d : values) {
                    bw.write(Double.toString(d));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                xIo.printStackTrace();
            }
});
```

This is allowed because `values` is not being changed. It always references the same array. It's just the array contents that are being changed.